# Graphing ECG Data from three different sources

Tags: plot, graphing, data-processing

I've got three sets of data from an ECG. One from an Arduino, an MSP432 and a CC3200. I'm looking to graph the data from these and be able to interpret it, also possibly be able to do a real-time version of it.

What should I do for this (Would I use software or specific code)? The data from the arduino for example looks like this (truncated quite a bit was very large)

```
    // Arduino Due with Olimex 57600 
var y = [[604,14262],[719,14266],[543,14270],[407,14274],[565,14278],[722,14282],[578,14286],[414,14290],[526,14294],[708,14298],[618,14302],
```

Also, what would be the relation of Fourier Analysis to these kinds of data sets? Someone suggested it to me but I'm not exactly sure what it'd do

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a wireless ECG project using CC3200 and let me tell you what i have done.

I have connected an AFE to my CC3200 via SPI and read ECG samples at 500Hz. I have implemented software filtering on these samples. Further i have connected my CC3200 and a PC to common Access Point. My CC3200 sends this ECG data to the PC which runs an application to plot the ECG in real-time.

Regarding your questions:-

1)**What should I do for this (Would I use software or specific code)? The data from the arduino for example looks like this (truncated quite a bit was very large)**

This means you have already sampled and read ECG data and stored it in your Arduino.

2)**what would be the relation of Fourier Analysis to these kinds of data sets?**

If you want to implement software filtering, you will need Fourier analysis as filters would be designed based on frequency components.
In my project, i have used Wavelets.

I have few questions for you:-

1) How have you extracted ECG data (have you used any analog front-end) and what is the sampling frequency ?

2) Have you implemented any filtering on the ECG (software or hardware) ?

3) How have you stored the data (what does [604,14262]... denote) ?

4) Where exactly do you want to plot the ECG (on TFT, mobile phone, PC...) ?